# libcurl with client certificate,i get an error "Unable to load client key -8178. * NSS error -8178"

Tags: libcurl

when i run this code ,i got error info :

- About to connect() to 10.12.190.155 port 443 (#0)
- Trying 10.12.190.155... * connected
- Connected to 10.12.190.155 (10.12.190.155) port 443 (#0)
- Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
- CAfile: /home/wh/work/sslkey/ca.crt
  CApath: none
- Unable to load client key -8178.
- NSS error -8178
- Closing connection #0
- Problem with the local SSL certificate

CURL *curl;
    CURLcode res;

```
//static const char *pClientCert = "/home/wh/work/sslkey/user1.pem";

curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_DEFAULT);
curl = curl_easy_init();

if(curl)
{
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1L);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "https://10.12.190.155/");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "/home/wh/work/sslkey/ca.crt");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl,CURLOPT_SSLCERT,"/home/wh/work/sslkey/user1.pem");
    res = curl_easy_perform(curl);
          /* Check for errors */
    if(res != CURLE_OK)
        fprintf(stderr, "curl_easy_perform() failed: %s\n",
            curl_easy_strerror(res));
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);
}

curl_global_cleanup();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no `curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_SSLKEY, "key_file_path");` in your code to get your key. Also it is unclear your user1.pem contains both the key and cert or not?

If the answer is no, you need to provide the key.pem file using the above command. If you convert your key from .p12 file then check for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27105058/1485809) issue as well.

Read [this](https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/simplessl.html) to write the code correctly.