# cURL with SSL certificates fails: error 58 unable to set private key file

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate

I'm trying to connect to a remote host using cURL. The connection requires the use of a certificate and a private key which is password protected. So far I'm unsuccessful with this code below:

```
<?php
    $wsdl       = 'https://domain.com/?wsdl';
    $certFile   = getcwd() . '/auth/cert.pem';
    $keyFile    = getcwd() . '/auth/key.pem';
    $password   = 'pwd';

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,           $wsdl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLCERT,       $certFile);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEYPASSWD,  $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLKEY,        $keyFile);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    #curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
    $output = curl_exec($ch);

    var_dump(curl_errno($ch));
    var_dump(curl_error($ch));
```

The result I keep getting is error `58`: `unable to set private key file: '/home/.../domains/.../public_html/auth/key.pem' type PEM`.

Things I've tried so far:

- Check if the key-file is readable as suggested here: [Unable to use libcurl to access a site requiring client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124289/unable-to-use-libcurl-to-access-a-site-requiring-client-authentication). Trying to pass the file through `openssl_private_key()` gives me a resource, and not a boolean. So this seems good.
- Switch the order of the content in the key.pem file as suggested here: [Unable to use libcurl to access a site requiring client authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124289/unable-to-use-libcurl-to-access-a-site-requiring-client-authentication). No luck so far.
- Played around with some other options like `SLL_VERIFY_PEER`, `SSL_VERIFY_HOST`, `SSL_CERTTYPE` and other options which seemed trivial regarding the official PHP-docs. No luck so far.

I'm pretty sure the problem lies somehwere in my configuration, but I'm not sure where to look.

Comment: "*Switch the order of the content in the key.pem*". You `key.pem` file (which contains the private key) should only really contain 1 PEM-encoded section (for the private key). It's the order of the cert file you might need to change. The client-cert for this private key should be at the top.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I've fixed this problem. I think, due to the number of questions regarding this issue and number of different solutions, others will benefit from the solution. Here goes:

I used the `openssl` CLI program to convert the .p12 key-file to a .pem key-file. The trick is the way the conversion takes place.

First I converted it with this command and I had the issue as described in the question:

`openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -nodes -clcerts`

While the command below did the actual trick:

`openssl pkcs12 -in key.p12 -out key.pem -clcerts`

For more info please see the source I used: https://community.qualys.com/docs/DOC-3273

Comment: `-nodes` removes the encryption on the key, which may conflict with you trying to use a password in this case.

Comment: Thanks for the additional info. I wasn't aware of that.

Comment: Did the trick for me! After days of being stuck on this! Thank You

Comment: Seems this page may explain the command line options: https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man1/openssl-pkcs12.html

Answer (score 3):

Just in case this is useful to others searching for this problem, I ended up discovering that CURLOPT_SSLCERT and CURLOPT_SSLKEY don't seem to work with relative paths.

This is with WAMP, php version 5.5 on Windows.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when using the `curl` and when searching found this question.  I was using the command `curl --key my.pem https://example.com/`

The solution that worked for me was to add the `--cert` option and point to the same PEM file.  Apparently, the PEM file (in my case) had the key as well as the certificate.

I tested it with the curl command:

```
curl --cert my.pem  --key my.pem https://example.com/my/url
```