# cURL error 58 while trying to access soap webserver

Tags: php, ssl, curl, certificate, nusoap

I'm trying to call (via PHP script) a remote (SOAP) webserver over https, it requires a password protected certificate.
I'm using **nuSoap** for making the call but I always get the following error

**nusoap_client: got wsdl error: Getting https://ws-t.pitre.tn.it/wcfrouting/wsdl/Documents.wsdl - HTTP ERROR: cURL ERROR: 58: unable to use client certificate (no key found or wrong pass phrase?)**

```
require_once("../nusoap/lib/nusoap.php");

$pitre_wsdl = "https://ws-t.pitre.tn.it/wcfrouting/wsdl/Documents.wsdl";
$client = new nusoap_client($pitre_wsdl, "wsdl");
$err = $client->getError();

if ($err) {
    print("Error");
    exit();
}

$client->setCredentials(
    "",
    "",
    "certificate",
    array (
        "sslcertfile"   =>  "../pitre/cert.p12",
        "sslkeyfile"    =>  "../pitre/cert.p12",
        "certpassword"  =>  "mypass",
        "verifypeer"    =>  FALSE,
        "verifyhost"    =>  FALSE
    )
);

$result = $client->call(
    "GetTemplatesDocuments",
    array (
        "CodeAdm"   =>  "myCode"
    )
);
```

With the browser I can access the wisdl without problems. I tried the following answer:

[cURL with SSL certificates fails: error 58 unable to set private key file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27102176/curl-with-ssl-certificates-fails-error-58-unable-to-set-private-key-file)

I got the same result.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, my solution is the following:

I wasn't able to make it work with **nu_soap** so I switched to **SoapClient**

Fist of all I had to convert my p12 certificate to pem format using openssl

```
openssl pkcs12 -in certificato.p12 -out certificato.pem -clcerts
```

Then I downloaded the CA certificates from here https://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html

Here's my working code

```
$params->a              = "a";
$params->b               = "b";
$params->c               = "c";
$params->d               = "d";
$params->e               = "e"; 

$context = stream_context_create(array (
    "ssl"   =>  array (
        "verify_peer"       =>  false,
        "verify_peer_name"  =>  true,
        "local_cert"        =>  getcwd()."\certificato.pem",  //complete path is mandatory
        "passphrase"        =>  "mypassphrase",
        "allow_self_signed" =>  true
    ),
    "https" =>  array (
        "curl_verify_ssl_peer"  =>  false,
        "curl_verify_ssl_host"  => false
    )
));

$pitre_client = new SoapClient($pitre_wsdl, array (
    "trace"             =>  1,
    "exceptions"        =>  true,
    "location"          =>  "https://ws-t.pitre.tn.it/wcfrouting/servicerouter.svc",
    "cafile"            =>  getcwd()."\cacert.pem", //complete path is mandatory
    "stream_context"    =>  $context
));

// the call
$response = $pitre_client->GetTemplatesDocuments(
    array (
        'request' => $params  //request key can be different
    )
);
```

I hope this will help someone facing the same issue